# handling a lot of sockets in a server efficiently

Tags: java, performance, sockets, server

I have to write a program in which clients send the server some number and wait to its response, other random number. It works Infinitely-send number and wait for response and so on...

I would like to write a server which gets a lot of connections ( and creates sockets) how can I do that in effeicient way (without creating thread to every socket created)?

Is it better to open and close sockets for every request and response?

Is there a way to send answer over a socket when I don't know which one is the right socket, but I know that all the sockets starts from the same client computer and I know the port source of the client 
(I thought about making sockets array)

Comment: you could use a broker with a bounded queue to reuse threads as they become available

Comment: How about you try to get the standard thread-per-socket way work first, before worrying about the future. It's not a good idea to concentrate on performance issues when you know very little about sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I do that in effeicient way (without creating thread to every socket created)?

You are assuming without proof that a new thread per socket is inefficient. It isn't.

> Is it better to open and close sockets for every request and response?

No. Take a look at the history of HTTP. The major change between 1.0 and 1.1 was the introduction of persistent connections, which was done regardless of server-side architectures.

> Is there a way to send answer over a socket when I don't know which one is the right socket

I don't understand how that situation could possibly arise. The answer only makes sense in the context of a specific session, which is associated with a specific socket. If you aren't retaining that information you should be. It's just a data structure problem.

> but I know that all the sockets starts from the same client computer and I know the port source of the client (I thought about making sockets array)

If you can remember the source port you can remember the socket itself. Again, this is just a data structure problem. And there is no need for the assumption/constraint that all connections are from the same client. And unless that client is multi-threaded there is no need for multiple connections from it at all.

Comment: I meant that I  run more than one client program from the same computer